# Using importXML with a php populated website and scraping to googlesheets

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets-query

I am trying to import data from this website using `IMPORTXML` into a googlesheet
http://14.139.247.11/citywx/city_weather.php?id=42488

I want to scrape the data at 
Minimum Temp (oC)

Loading data from this table to sheets using `IMPORTHTML` works just fine using this `=IMPORTHTML("http://14.139.247.11/citywx/city_weather.php?id=42488","table",2)`

But trying to scrape using `IMPORTXML` is not working. 
Using chrome developer tools I copied the XML path and it shows to be

`/html/body/center/font/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/font`

This returns:

`NA ie.("Imported Content is Empty")`

I copied the entire html on my server. The scraping works locally when I remove the bolded "font" from 
/html/body/center/**font**/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/font
 and set it to:
`/html/body/center/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/font`

However it still fails on the original site.

It does not look like a case of dynamic website since `importHTML` works and I could not find any javascript running. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Index to get the row and column position for the min temp from the imported table using IMPORTHTML not IMPORTXML. The source is HTML not XML.

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://14.139.247.11/citywx/city_weather.php?id=42488","table",2),4,2)
```

---

Sheet:

[image: Result]

Comment: That was the backup in case we could not get importxml working. That strategy works fine. Thanks !

Comment: Not actually ! Used the backup :) However I still could not come to terms with the fact that I could not make it work as expected.

Comment: I was not able to accept it as answer. Probably because u commented instead of answering.  Do I need to do anything differently

Comment: If you try to upvote that won't work. So that is probably what you tried. You can always accept answers to your own questions.

Comment: Accepted as answer :)